# Is this an Apple compiler v14 optimization bug?

Tags: c++, macos, clang++, xcode14

Source code:

```
#include <cstdio>

static const char encodeBase64Table[64 + 1] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

int main() {
    // create decoding table
    unsigned long invalid = 64;
    unsigned long decodeBase64Table[256] = {};
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        decodeBase64Table[i] = invalid;
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        decodeBase64Table[(unsigned char)encodeBase64Table[i]] = i;
    }
    printf("decodeBase64Table[65] = %lu\n", decodeBase64Table[65]);

    return 0;
}
```

Apple Clang 11.0.3 (expected output, even with -O3):

```
/t/s/1673994196 ❯❯❯ /usr/bin/clang++ --version
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
/t/s/1673994196 ❯❯❯ /usr/bin/clang++ -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -O3 -std=c++17 a.cpp
/t/s/1673994196 ❯❯❯ ./a.out
decodeBase64Table[65] = 0
```

Apple Clang 14.0.0 (unexpected output, only with -O3):

```
/t/s/1673994196 ❯❯❯ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
/t/s/1673994196 ❯❯❯ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -O3 -std=c++17 a.cpp
/t/s/1673994196 ❯❯❯ ./a.out
decodeBase64Table[65] = 64
```

Comment: _"Is this an Apple compiler bug?"_ - almost certainly not. Compilers go through a great deal of testing. What debugging have you done here?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I've tested this with various versions of Clang, GCC and Apple Clang versions. Only Apple's Clang v14 produces a different output.

Comment: but you have not specified any c++ standard in either compilation.   the default probably changed.

Comment: @RichardBarber Updated the question. Using `-std=c++17` on both.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @RichardBarber This code should have the same meaning in all versions of C++, and also in all versions of C if you replace the #include with the C one, and get rid of the unneeded initialisation of decodeBase64Table.

Comment: So eliminates that possibility.  The previous behavior may not have been the correct optimization, or the default implementation of an optimizer flag may have changed.

Comment: To me it seems like it’s optimizing out a cast from string literal when you try to load the table in the last loop.

Comment: ```#include <string>    
static const std::string encodeBase64Table = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
```

Comment: The `std::string` will not get -O3'd out.

Comment: @RichardBarber If two compilers produce different results, then at least one of the two is true (1) at least one of the compilers has a bug, or (2) the code has a bug in the form of undefined, implementation-defined, or unspecified behaviour. Can you show such a bug in the code?

Comment: @n.m. answer your own question or raise it in a new question.

Comment: @RichardBarber My answer is that there is no bug in the program, there is a bug in the compiler. Should be clear from the above.

Comment: Which compilation is in error, though?

Comment: Either Apple's clang v14 under -O3, or all the versions of all the compilers from all the vendors except that one. One of the two, there are no more possibilities. What do *you* think? No wait, there is the third one—they are all wrong. It looks like one needs to read the standard to settle this...